# Preventing bleed through of transitive dependencies

Tags: jpa, sonarqube

This is a SonarQube and JPA question in the context of a multi-module Maven project.

In JPA, the persistent domain model classes will be annotated @Entity and will subclass Entity.  The module "myproject-domain" which contains these classes must have a dependency on the JPA API.

Unfortunately this means that other modules which depend upon module "my-domain" will inherit the compile-time dependency on the JPA API.  Our intention is that developers will only invoke JPA itself from within one module "myproject-repository".  Other modules, e.g. "myproject-app" will have a dependency on "myproject-domain" and on the INTERFACEs of the repositories.

My intention is to prevent code in "myproject-app" from having access to JPA artefacts at compile time, e.g. EntityManager.

I can see two ways to do this.
1. Use a restricted JPA library in the "myproject-domain" module which contains ONLY the Entity and Annotation classes.
2. Get SonarQube to enforce a restriction on the use of JPA classes other than Entity in all modules other than "myproject-domain" and "myproject-repository".

Is this possible in SonarQube?
Is there an already-available restricted JPA library such as I have described?

Many thanks, Robin.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the rule template [squid:ArchitecturalConstraint](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AArchitecturalConstraint) to create a custom rule which does not allow calls from `myproject-app` packages to `javax.persistence.**`

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with pure maven means. Just flag the dependency to JPA-API as optional in "my-domain". If needed, duplicate this optional dependency in "myproject-repository".
See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html